# Issue with LDAP + HttpBasicAuth in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, ldap, basic-authentication

I have a config like this:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Then, BasicAuthenticationFilter

```
<bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="BauthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="BauthenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

Entry point and manager were descrbed like that:

```
<bean id="BauthenticationEntryPoint"   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Name Of Your Realm"/>
</bean>
<bean id="BauthenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And finally

```
        <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>sAMAccountName={0}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
            <constructor-arg value=""/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When I try to access /index.jsp I shown an stadart http auth window that requesting me my username and password. When I type it into form and press Enter nothing goes on - an auth window just reloads and nothing more.

Where I made a mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Enable debug logging for **org.springframework.security** package and show exception please.

Comment: It seems like there is no exception during auth process itself.
Maybe I didn't enable debug logging? How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: If I hit a cancel button in auth window ,of course, message "Error 401: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken" will be shown

Comment: I add
    <security:authentication-manager>
             <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

and now I get an Error 401: Bad credentials

Comment: It means that your login/password combination is wrong

Comment: yeah, I know.
But they are certainly right.
Are there any reasons why this exception may be thrown?

Comment: password is encoded? corresponding password encoder is defined in your security.xml?

Comment: do you mean this string?
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

Comment: yes. inject it into your auth provider

Comment: Well, now it's looks like
    <security:authentication-manager>
             <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider">
                 <security:password-encoder hash="md5" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
             </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

but I now get aCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot have child elements when used with 'ref' attribute.

As far as I know it was fixed in 3.1.X.I'm using 3.1.3. But I still get this error

Comment: Try to replace bean id="ldapAuthProvider" by **ldap-authentication-provider** element. Declare it as a child of authentication manager

Comment: @MaksymDemidas, sorry, but I'm afraid I didn't understand what exactly did you mean. Can you please give me a short example?

Comment: sorry, it looks like password encoder is not necessary if you use BindAuthenticator. Are you sure that your DN pattern is right? Corresponding user is present in LDAP?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. This user presented in LDAP tree with sAMAccountName I typed into user field of login form.
I'm really sure that we are close to moment of solving this problem, cause Bad credential error makes me hope for me made a stupid mistake somewhere.
Sorry, @MaksymDemidas, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Enable as much logging as you can / debug spring code. Find a cause of BadCredentials exception. In some cases user may not be found by BindAuthenticator and you must setup additional LdapUserSearch bean as explained here http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-searchobjects

Comment: ok,@MaksymDemidas, thanks a lot for time you spent for me!
I'll try to do what you advice and if something will go right - I'll post it here

Comment: You are welcome. To be sure that BindAuthenticator is enough you can do the same steps from command line http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/network.920/a96579/comtools.htm#632632

Answer (score 0):

Declaring beans independently does not automatically mean they will override the equivalent beans in a namespace configuration. For example, `<http-basic />` will add a `BasicAuthenticationFilter` to the filter chain (and an entry point) and the fact that you have declared your own instances will have no effect.

So as it stands, your namespace configuration is ignoring the filter and authentication beans you have declared. You could try using:

```
<http use-expressions="true" authentication-manager-ref="BauthenticationManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

which will make the configuration use your authentication manager. Alternatively you could just use the standard namespace syntax for the authentication manager and drop your `BauthenticationManager` bean:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Either way, you should probably read the [namespace chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-config) of the reference  manual to get an overview of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @LukeTaylor!
But those fact that I got Bad credential error makes me think that the right auth provider is working on. And besides, if I replace userDnPatterns with user filter that I know will give me no result on user search in LDAP tree, I will get LDAP 32 error - user not found.

Comment: In that case, the configuration you've posted is either incomplete or isn't the one you are running with. There is no way the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` you have defined is being included in the namespace security filter chain created by `<http/>`. Perhaps you've omitted the `authentication-manager` namespace declaration? The filter, entry point and authentication manager bean are still redundant and are just confusing things.